# Reading a FPT File

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I would like to read a FPT/DBF file I have tried to load the file with any of these

- FoxPro 7
- FoxPro 8
- FoxPro 9

when I edit the FPT I see text in the file I want to change but when I browse the file(FPT) in FoxPro it doesn't show the values I want to change but just gibberish shows in the table columns. It is reading the different columns but the data I am looking for is not there. Any ideas at all would be helpful thanks!

Comment: Have you saved any edits to the FPT file? You may have changed the structure and so it is now unreadable by VFP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using VFP directly, you should just be able to

```
USE YourTable
browse normal
```

Then, scroll left/right until you find a column that shows "Memo" instead of actual content.  This field is what has the actual content behind the FPT file.  If you double click it, it will bring up the content.

If you are looking for specific text within the memo, you can do

```
browse normal for atc( "looking for", WithinWhatColumn ) > 0
```

This will show you any records that have the content in question.  You can then open each one and modify all you want.  If you want to do some BULK replacing, you can do that too, such as

```
replace WithinWhatColumn with strtran( WithinWhatColumn, "looking for", "change to this" );
   for atc( "looking for", WithinWhatColumn ) > 0
```

**EDIT per feedback**

No problem on the .CDX.  VFP keeps files in "sets" when applicable (.DBF, .CDX, .FPT).  .CDX files contain the indexes directly associated to a single table, so when the table is opened, so too are the corresponding indexes.  If a file has one or more MEMO fileds, then the corresponding .FPT file is created too for the variable length "memo" content.

In addition, the building blocks within VFP are also DBF-driven, just file name suffix changed... including

```
Forms:  (.scx/.sct)  corresponds to .dbf/.fpt
Visual Class Libraries:  (.vcx/.vct)
Reports: (.frx/.frt)
Projects: (.pjx/.pjt)
```

You can actually use any of these with the explicit suffix corresponding to the dbf portion and look at what it has inside.

use YourForm.scx
browse
it has a record for every control on a given form, where it was derived, its properties, base class association, method code, etc..

Comment: DRapp thanks for the explanation I have a CDX, a DBF, and a FPT no VFP is that a issue ?

Comment: YourTable in the answer above should be the path to the DBF file

Comment: @WilliamMioch, no, in VFP, the "USE" command is to actually open a specific table... if the person wants to explicitly use a fully qualified path AND table name they can do that.  If not, it assumes current path for the table.  If it can't find it in the current directory, it would popup a dialog and ask you where to find the file.

Comment: Didn't realise it prompted since I always use the path - easier to type you see.

Answer (score 1):

you should have no problem reading the table with any version of Foxpro! It sounds as if the file is corrupt or has been encrypted in some way.

It the table a free table air part of a database container ?

Comment: if it is a free table, zip it and send it to hugh.braithwaite@foxsoft.net